# R: openxlsx and sqldf

Tags: sql, r, excel

I have a question about using R to read in a file from Excel. I am reading in a few tabs from an Excel worksheet and performing some basic sql commands and merging them using sqldf. My problem is my RAM gets bogged down a lot after reading in the Excel data. I can run the program but had to install 8GB of RAM to not use like 80% of my available RAM.

I know if I have a text file, I can read it in directly using read.csv.sql() and performing the sql in the "read" command so my RAM doesn't get bogged down. I also know you can save the table as a tempfile() so it doesn't take up RAM space. The summarized data using sqldf does not have very many rows so does not bog the memory down.

The only solution I've been able to come up with is to set up an R program that just reads in the data and creates the text files. Close R down and run a second program that reads it back in from the text files using sqldf and performs the SQL commands and merges the data. I don't like this solution as much because it still involves using a lot of RAM in the initial read-in program and uses 2 programs which I would like to just use 1.

I could also manually create the text file from the Excel tab but they are some updates being made on a regular basis at the moment so I'd rather not have to do that. Also I'd like something more automated to create the text files.

For reference, the tables are are 4 tables of the following sizes:

1. 3k rows x 9 columns
2. 200K x 20
3. 4k x 16
4. 80k x 13
5. 100K x 12

My read-in's look like this:

```
    table<-read.xlsx(filename, sheet="Sheet")
    summary<-sqldf("SQL code")
    rm(table)
    gc()
```

I have tried running the rm(table) and gc() commands after each read-in and sql manipulation (after which I no longer need the entire table) but these commands do not seem to free up much RAM. Only by closing the R session do I get the 1-2 GB back.

So is there any way to read in an Excel file to R and not take up RAM in the process? I also want to note this is on a work computer for which I do not have admin rights so anything I would want to install requiring such rights I would have to request from IT which is a barrier I'd like to avoid.

Comment: You should know, R will still have the memory allocated even if nothing is stored there and will reuse the memory available.  So if you have 2gb of data, remove them from R, and reload them it will use that same memory.  I'd give this a read [Advanced R: Memory](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html)

Comment: And do understand that memory management issues are OS-specific and this may not apply to *NIX boxes.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I will go through the advanced link and I am using Windows 7 if that helps.

Comment: If you don't want to keep the data in memory, you should not use `read.xlsx`. It is much better to dump xlsx to csv directly, not loading data to R.